# Either unexpected token or converting circular structure with JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to write a simple client-server testing site to get a better understanding of sending JSON objects to and from both sides.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Hello Express</title>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello, Express!</h1>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
     <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br>
      </form>
      <button onclick="postData()">Post Data</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
async function postData() {
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/hello', {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
      body: JSON.stringify({
          name:"dean",
          age:21
      }) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    result = JSON.parse(response)
    var para = document.createElement("P");               // Create a <p> element
    para.innerText = result;               // Insert text
    document.body.appendChild(para);
}
```

server.js

```
// server.js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(req)
    res.send(result);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The idea is to eventually make it so that the values entered in the inputs will be converted into a JSON object, sent to the server and then have one of its attributes returned. Right now however, I am simply trying to send a fixed JSON object to the server and get it back. Using this current implementation however gets me a circular structure error. I have attempted other formats to do this but they then result in an unexpected token error (token o a position 1). If anyone can let me know if I am overlooking anything critical please let me know, I will be using this knowledge for a bigger project later on and would prefer to understand it now as opposed to later.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues you're having is that you are not properly parsing `JSON` payloads on both the client and server. I've added comments with suggestions on how to fix your code, so have a look below.

On the `server-side`, you should use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` middlewares to parse incoming requests with `JSON` payloads.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded` to
// parse incoming requests with JSON payloads
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
app.post("/hello", (req, res, next) => {
  // `req.body` is a native object since `express.json()`
  // and `express.urlencoded()` are taking care of the payload,
  // no need for `JSON.parse()` here
  const { firstName, lastName, age } = req.body;

  console.log("firstName", firstName, "lastName", lastName, "age", age);

  // alternatively, using `dot` notation
  console.log(
    "firstName", req.body.firstName,
    "lastName", req.body.lastName,
    "age", req.body.age
  );

  res.status(200).json({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    age,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  });
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

On the `client-side`, you should call `response.json()` after your `fetch` request resolves with some data that's coming back from the server. Make sure you `await` it since `response.json()` returns a `Promise`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form><!-- form elements go here... --></form>
    <button onclick="handleOnSubmit()">Post Data</button>

    <!-- display results here... -->
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your `JavaScript` file, do the following:

```js
function handleOnSubmit() {
  const data = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 21 };
  async function postData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/hello", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      // Make sure you call `response.json()` to parse
      // response into native JavaScript object, no need for `JSON.parse()`
      const payload = await response.json();
      const { firstName, lastName, age, receivedAt } = payload;
      const p = document.createElement("p");

      p.textContent = `${firstName}, ${lastName}, ${age}, ${receivedAt}`;
      document.getElementById("result").appendChild(p);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  postData();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There just needed to be a listen at the end of the server with the port but now it works great! My Next question is how on the server I could get one specific attribute of the json object that was sent over?

Comment: @Frigglefrack you mean like `req.body.firstName`? All those properties that you've sent from the `frontend` are accessible on the `req.body` object, so just use the `dot` notation - see the edit.

Comment: @Frigglefrack are you still having issues?